tailwind css: adding space between element makes layout strange
I'm working on a nextjs project with tailwind css enabled. Here is my page.tsx code:
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-row flex-wrap items-center justify-center space-x-16 space-y-16">
      <a href="/" style={{
        textDecoration: "none",
        fontSize: "40px",
        border: "3px solid #351435",
        padding: "40px 80px",
      }}>
        button
      </a>
      <a href="/" style={{
        textDecoration: "none",
        fontSize: "40px",
        border: "3px solid #351435",
        padding: "40px 80px",
      }}>
        button
      </a>
      <a href="/" style={{
        textDecoration: "none",
        fontSize: "40px",
        border: "3px solid #351435",
        padding: "40px 80px",
      }}>
        button
      </a>
      <a href="/" style={{
        textDecoration: "none",
        fontSize: "40px",
        border: "3px solid #351435",
        padding: "40px 80px",
      }}>
        button
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}

The layout I got is strange, only the first button seems to be positioned correctly (centered vertically and horizontally), the rest of the buttons are all placed at the bottom right corner of its container. See it in the image below:
layout
Thank you in advance, this has been bugging me for a while now and I tried ask multiple chat bots (chat gpt, gemini, copilot) and still can not solve it.
What I'm hoping is that all the buttons (html  tag) can be placed in one line and with some space between each of them and the buttons can be wrapped to new lines if I add more buttons to my page.
I have tried to add display: block and display: inline-flex to the style but the problem still persists.

That space-y-xx class is adding margin to all subsequent elements after the first child, and the same thing with the space-x-xxx class. Try removing those and just giving your parent the same amount of padding with py-16 or the equivalent for px-.


What I'm hoping is that all the buttons (html tag) can be placed in
one line and with some space between each of them and the buttons can
be wrapped to new lines if I add more buttons to my page.

You can use gap utility to do that


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex flex-wrap justify-center gap-20">
  <a href="/" class="border border-[#351435] px-20 py-10 text-2xl"> button </a>
  <a href="/" class="border border-[#351435] px-20 py-10 text-2xl"> button </a>
  <a href="/" class="border border-[#351435] px-20 py-10 text-2xl"> button </a>
  <a href="/" class="border border-[#351435] px-20 py-10 text-2xl"> button </a>
</div>



Still if you want to use space utility, simple trick to fix that issue is adding empty element as the first child element


<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="flex flex-wrap justify-center space-x-16 space-y-16">
  <div></div>
  <a href="/" class="border border-[#351435] px-20 py-10 text-2xl"> button </a>
  <a href="/" class="border border-[#351435] px-20 py-10 text-2xl"> button </a>
  <a href="/" class="border border-[#351435] px-20 py-10 text-2xl"> button </a>
  <a href="/" class="border border-[#351435] px-20 py-10 text-2xl"> button </a>
</div>



But hope it wouldn't be a good solution than using gap utility
